# How to get the angle between polar coordinates without converting to cartesian

Tags: polar-coordinates, angle

I'm trying to work out a way to get the angle between two points given in polar coordinates, without first converting them to x,y. I (sort of) remember enough high school trig to do it with x,y but I'm stumped at trying to do it with r, theta. I've found the Haversine formula, but that's to find the central angle between two points on a circle. That's not the angle I mean. I mean the one you'd get from atan(y1 - y0 / x1 - x0) if you wanted to convert your polars to cartesians. I hope I'm expressing that right; I'm doing this with javascript, so I'm doing Math.atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0). But I'd like to do it with r, theta, if I could figure out a way.

P.S. Just 2D, not looking for any hugely generalized form, if that matters at all.

**Edit, in case it helps:**

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. It seems you have two points in (r,theta) form such as $(r_1, \theta_1)$ and $(r_2, \theta_2)$ and you want to know the difference in the angle?

Comment: Not the diffs in the two thetas; that's basing them from the origin. I mean the angle you'd get by treating one point as the origin, the angle from there to the other point. That's what I meant by y1 - y0 and x1 - x0, when using cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @GreatBigBore: I wish I could have a simple picture of what you are trying to find. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. I'm trying to think of a way I could draw this and post a pic. I could just draw it freehand and take a pic with my phone. Any ideas better than that?

Comment: @BabakS. Added a free-hand. I hope that doesn't make it even harder to understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the distance between the points using Cos Law

$$ d^2 = r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2 r_1 r_2 \cos( \theta_2 - \theta_1   )  $$

Now use Sine Law to get the angle $\alpha$ opposite $r_2$

$$
\frac{\sin \alpha}{ r_2} =\frac{\sin (\theta_2 - \theta_1 )}{ d}  
$$
The angle that the line joining the 2 points makes with the x-axis is just $\theta_1-\alpha$

Comment: It took me a while to get all the code doing precisely what you've described here, mostly because I was not clear on which point was "1" and which was "2", but now it works perfectly. I would never have found those formulas, and certainly never would have worked them out for myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: An equivalent (simpler) formula is ... $$ \tan^{-1}(\frac{r_1 \sin \theta_1-r_2 \sin \theta_2}{r_1 \cos \theta_1-r_2 \cos \theta_2}) $$

Comment: Wow, that is a lot simpler. It will be a good exercise to get it into my program. Thanks so much again. The code works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to figured out the angle that you want, so in the photo you will see that i don't use cartesian coordinates to solve the problem but if you take a look in the answer that i gave in the photo you can simplyfied the problem only using the conversion formulas of cartesian to polar coordinates like:

---

x=Rcos(θ) and

---

y=Rsin(θ)

[Solving Problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4OVA.jpg)

**sorry about the picture but i can not turn it**